# Integer Expression Expected : Bash

Tags: bash, shell

I read on stack overflow that we need quotes here and added quotes, but it ddn't helped.

```
array_length=${fileNames[@]}

COUNTER=0

while [ "$COUNTER" -lt "$array_length" ]; do
```

I get the error still. Please help. Completely new to bash

Comment: Your mention of a previous question should be a link (you can edit the question and fix it, explained in the help) to help with context.  But, just looking at the short piece you show, I see that you set a variable called `array_length` to a list of file names and then try to use it as a number.  Unless `fileNames` has only one element (in which case you wouldn't be using `[0]`) and it happens to be a number, that invocation of test can't possibly work.

Comment: Sorry about that, I'll try to find it again. Didn't help me so I closed it.

Comment: See [bash arrays](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arrays.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
array_length=${fileNames[@]}
```

should have been

```
array_length=${#fileNames[@]}
```

For the expected behaviour, your while loop should be:

```
while [ "$COUNTER" -lt "$array_length" ]
do
.
#do something
.
((COUNTER++)) # Equivalent to COUNTER=COUNTER+1
done
```

`${fileNames[@]}` expands to the whole array while prefixing it with `#` gives you the number of elements.

---

<sup>**Sidenotes**:</sup>

<sup>1. Don't forget to increment `COUNTER` inside while loop.</sup>

<sup>2. Try avoiding capitalized variables like `COUNTER` as they are usually reserved for the system.</sup>

Comment: Thanks, I'll accept it in 5 minutes. Can you also tell me what's wrong with this: "$COUNTER + 1" -lt "$array_length"
This one still gives an error, if any major concept, I'll open a new question.

Comment: @BhavyaArora : `counter+1` will not increment `counter`.

Comment: I don't want to increment it here, just want to compare it with the next number. How do I remove the error. And also what would increase the counter? let counter = counter + 1   ?

Comment: @BhavyaArora : Not sure what you wisht exactly, See the edit.

Comment: @mklement0 : Thankyou and as always,appreciated :)